# Is Starfire’s race related to Superman’s?

Tags: dc, superman, starfire

Starfire is from the planet Tameran. She looks humanoid, has the ability to fly, has super-strength and shoots energy beams out of her eyes.

Superman is from Krypton and has many of the same qualities. Are their species related?

Comment: Just to clarify a lot of alien superheroes tend to have similar abilities but that doesn't mean they are related in some way.

Answer (score 10):

They aren't really related... Tamaranians' abilities stem from them converting ultraviolet energy.  Also Starfire's ability to shoot bolts is due to experiments. And Tamaranians seem to be humanoid but are descended from a feline race.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamaran

[image: Blackfire and Starire]
Picture of Blackfire and Starfire (Teen Titans Cartoon)

[image]Starfire depiction in comics

> Tamaraneans are orange-skinned humanoid people who descended from a
>   feline-like race. Tamaraneans traditionally worship the goddess X'Hal.
>   Tamaraneans have the power to convert ultraviolet radiation into
>   energy for flight with the females producing a distinctive contrail
>   that seems to flow from their hair. They are ruled by their emotions
>   and were renowned as excellent warriors. Both Starfire and Blackfire
>   gained the ability to fire "starbolts", beams of energy, as a result
>   of experiments performed by the Psions.

Kryptonians on the other hand use the solar energy from different Suns to perform different feats.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptonian

[image]
Picture of Superman

> Kryptonians use solar energy from yellow, blue, or white stars on the
>   cellular and molecular levels to gain superhuman abilities.

Overall they are vastly different physically and in how they gain / use their powers.

Edit:  One of the few Tamaranians that can pass for human would probably be Starfire's sister in the Teen Titans cartoon because her eyes look normal opposed to Starfire's sclera (aka the part of an eye which is white on humans is green on Starfire)

Comment: So if Starfire's race is descended from cat-like beings, what about Superman's?

Comment: That's undetermined but since their physiology is similar to humans it can be guessed that they descended from primates on Krypton.